# Python: split string at last lower case letter

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to split a string at the last lower case letter in the string. Strings will always have at least one lower case letter. There will always be a space after the last lower case letter. There may be digits in the string.

This is the best I've come up with:

```
s = 'Arrived at location NEWARK NJ US'
for i, c in enumerate(reversed(s)):
    if c.islower():
        d = len(s) - i
        break
a = s[:d]
b = s[d+1:]
```

Is there a simpler or more pythonic way? Perhaps a readable regex?

Answer (score 4):

Through `re.split`.

```
>>> s = 'Arrived at location NEWARK NJ US'
>>> re.split(r'(?<=[a-z])\s+(?=[^a-z]*$)', s)
['Arrived at location', 'NEWARK NJ US']
```

- [`(?<=[a-z])`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) looks after to a lowercase letter.
- `\s+` Then match the following one or more space characters,
- **Only if**
- it's followed by [`(?=..)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- `[^a-z]*` Any character but not of a lowercase letter, zero or more times.
- `$` immediately followed by an end of the line. So it matches the spaces which was just after to the last lowercase letter.

**OR**

```
>>> s = "Arrived at location NEWARK NJ US"
>>> part1, part2 = re.findall(r'(.*[a-z])\s+(.*)', s)[0]
>>> part1
'Arrived at location'
>>> part2
'NEWARK NJ US'
```

**OR**

```
>>> s = "Arrived at location NEWARK NJ US"
>>> part1, part2 = re.search(r'(.*[a-z])\s+(.*)', s).groups()
>>> part1
'Arrived at location'
>>> part2
'NEWARK NJ US'
```

**OR**

re.split will return the delimiter if the delimiter was present within a capturing group.

```
>>> part1, part2 = [i for i in re.split(r'(.*[a-z])\s+', s) if not i == '']
>>> part1
'Arrived at location'
>>> part2
'NEWARK NJ US'
```

Comment: @foosion: that's regular expressions for you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Perhaps I should have said "simple regex" in the Q, but you'd probably give the same comment. :-)

Comment: @foosion: yup. I'd have posted the exact same regular expression; it fits your requirements.

Comment: i don't know what you mean by simple regex.

Comment: @AvinashRaj simple means easily readable by someone who is not very good with regular expressions. `?<=` and `?=` are not things I see frequently

Comment: @AvinashRaj update much nicer than the original for the regex challenged among us. You've inspired me to spend some time with regex.

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
s = 'Arrived at location NEWARK NJ US'
pos = re.search("[a-z]", s[::-1]).start()
a, b = s[:-pos], s[1 - pos:]
```

Result for `a`, `b`:

```
Arrived at location
NEWARK NJ US
```

The idea is to find the position of the last lower case letter by searching the reversed string.

If you expect multiple spaces after the last lower case letter:

```
start, end = re.search("\s+[a-z]", s[::-1]).span()
a, b = s[:1 - end], s[-start:]
```